# VBA code using sumproduct and indirect functions

Tags: excel, vba, sumproduct

I have a sheet containing the following formula in cell F10.
I would like to have a VBA code that will calculate this and place the value in cell

```
=SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(F4&":"&F5)),1)=7)*1)
```

Cell F4 contains a start date and F5 an end date

I tried the following but get a runtime error 438

```
With ActiveSheet.Range("F10")
        .Value = .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(" & Cells(4, 6) & ":" & Cells(5, 6) & ")),1)=7)*1)")
End With
```

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works.  First there is no Question in your Question.  Second, this is not a code for me, teach me to code, or show me where to start site.  This site helps overcome specific problems with existing code.  Please [edit] the post to include the code and a [mcve].  Also it would be good to visit [ask] and [tour]

Comment: Question have been updated

Comment: @ScottCraner I replaced the original Code with but still get runtime error 438

    With ActiveSheet.Range("F10")
        .Value = .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(ROW(INDIRECT(" & .Cells(4, 6).Address(0, 0) & ":" & .Cells(5, 6).Address(0, 0) & ")),1)=7)*1)")
    End With

Comment: Evaluate is a member function of Application object, not Range. `.Value = Application.Evaluate(...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix your specific issue Evaluate is not part of the Range.  You need to use the worksheet level instead.

Also it is good to return the `.Value2` which will strip the format and return the double.

And you do not need the INDIRECT as you are already using a string

```
    With ActiveSheet
        Range("F10").Value = .Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT((WEEKDAY(ROW(" & Cells(4, 6).Value2 & ":" & Cells(5, 6).Value2 & "),1)=7)*1)")
    End With
```

To do it solely with vba:

```
With ActiveSheet
    Dim st As Long
    st = .Cells(4, 6).Value2
    
    Dim ed As Long
    ed = .Cells(5, 6).Value2
    
    Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = 0
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = st To ed
        If i Mod 7 = 0 Then cnt = cnt + 1 '0 = Saturday, 1 = Sunday, and so on.
    Next i
    
    .Cells(10, 6) = cnt
End With
```

Comment: Thanks this solved my issue.  I am actually trying to get the VBA code and not use the worksheet formula but my skills are not quite there yet.

Comment: @TiaanVanCoppenhagen see edit.